# How to set firebase onAuthStateChanged listener in React-native

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-authentication

I'm trying to use firebase database for my project(Expo for react-native)

What I understand is that firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged listens for the signed in/out status of the user. So when user logs off, it should be triggered again.

I'm not sure exactly where to locate the onAuthStateChanged method in react-native. At the moment I've located it in componentDidMount, like this:

```
componentDidMount() {
firebase.auth().onAuthStateChanged(user => {
  if (user) {
    console.log("logged in");
  } else {
    console.log("not logged in");
  }
});
}
```

It works when the component loads, but the problem is onAuthStateChanged method does not trigger when I press signout button(which has firebase.auth().signOut() method during OnPress).

I know componentDidMount only loads once when component mounts. 
So where should I locate onAuthStateChanged method so that when I press logout, it will listen for the signout action and triggers the onAuthStateChanged method again?

Thank you.

Comment: You may locate it in componentDidMount of your App.js component.

Comment: @Yossi will it change anything? app.js is only called once at the beginning to doesn't it?

Comment: @hyuklee onAuthStateChanged start a listener which "listen on auth state change". it doesn't stop with the end of app.js rendering.

Comment: @barracus could you elaborate by giving some code examples? I'm not sure how to implement that

Comment: @hyuklee of course. Probably the right implementation using Expo is the one provided on Expo documentation here: https://docs.expo.io/versions/latest/guides/using-firebase#listening-for-authentication. I think it's ok to put listener out of componentDidMount. If you call a firebase init (firebase.initializeApp(config); ) somewhere in your app, the place where i wuold put it is under it.